# Let me See “Questions that Need an Answer” across sites I'm active on in one place

Tags: feature-request, question-lists

I'd like the ability to see "Questions that have no accepted answer" for all of my sites at once instead of having to manually go through them individually by site and look.

Preferably with a toggle to limit it to "Questions that haven't had an answer submitted yet".

Comment: Are you sure? Because that's a lot of questions you have to wade through ...

Comment: It's better than having to manually go to the 10+ sites I'm interested in and wading through the questions at each one there.

Comment: How would you select which sites you're interested in?  And how would you prevent site confusion?  If it's all amalgamated in a single list, I'd bet there'd be people answering Cooking questions with Programmer knowledge (ie. how do I salt the hash?).  That's likely a not inconsequential issue.

Comment: For me, "my sites" are ones that I have elected to join. This is basically like a useful version of the hot questions list (which is site agnostic), but it's "Questions in subjects you're interested in that need answers".

Comment: You're actually a part of 29 sites.  So...you want *all* 29 sites in one amalgamated list?

Comment: @fbueckert My preference would be to show me all questions across all sites I'm a member of which match this set of criteria: unanswered (ideally 0 answers, but net 0 score across >0 answers is *ok*), tags I watch minus any tags I ignore, score > 1 (or maybe score > 0).

Comment: Okay.  And how do you differentiate between them?  How do you ensure you know which question is for which site?

Comment: The same way you do in the hot network questions list, they have icons showing them. Your concern doesn't make sense. Even if I did somehow think that a salt the hash problem was a cooking question before I clicked on it, it would be completely obvious once I clicked on it that it was in the coding site instead. I wouldn't be likely to answer the question completely ignoring the text in the question and all the flair that shows I'm in the coding site.

Comment: Re: 29 sites: Exactly.